# How much Whisper is reliable?

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper

I'm thinking on how to implement a P2P messaging platform using Whisper (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper), but before of starting designing a protocol on top of it and work on its implementation, I have some questions about the protocol itself and on the project status:

- Do you know if it's suitable for production environment?
- Is there a web service that provides stats about Whisper nodes, such as network coverage, network load, average latency, etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know if it's suitable for production environment?

AFAIK it is still in PoC (Proof of Concept) phase - so I would say no

> Is there a web service that provides stats about Whisper nodes, such as network coverage, network load, average latency, etc?

I am not aware of any web service that fulfills your criteria

Depending on what you want to do you might also want to look into PSS - perhaps you do not need the darkness that whisper focuses on in your use-case so PSS might be an option.